# How to Call C++ Setters & Getters from Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-ffi

I know how to call pure C++ functions from Haskell, but wondering how to get GHC to accept functions that have side effects.

I want Haskell to have read-only access to a C++ linked list, and exclusive write access to a C++ variable. For example:

```
class node {
    // Some other class makes a linked list out of these
    int x;
    node* previous;
    node* next;
}

class myHaskellInterface {
    node* presentLocation; // C++ decides what is regarded as current location

    int getVal() {
        // Haskell calls this to get information from C++
        return presentLocation->x;
    }

    int haskellResults; // Store Haskell output here

    void setVal(int x) {
        // Haskell calls this to pass information back
        haskellResults = x;
    }

};
```

Even though getVal() doesn't have side effects, it is part of a class that obviously has side effects, so it's not clear to me whether sneaky tricks are required to get GHC to accept it.

setVal(int) clearly has side effects, so how do you make GHC not care?

Comment: Is there a reason a foreign import with an IO type of a C symbol isn't what you're wanting?  You'd declare the C extern in the cxx file and have `foreign import ccall "externed_getVal" getVal :: CxxObj -> IO CInt` in Haskell.

Comment: No, there's no reason why that wouldn't be it. I read somewhere that FFI functions are not allowed to have side effects. I guess what I'm really asking is  1) is that true and 2) if so, what to do about it.

Comment: It is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the production of side effects isn't the issue.  It's "impure" versus "pure" functions that are important.  While `getVal` doesn't *cause* side effects, it *relies* on side effects to produce a value because it consults `presentLocation`.  In other words, it's an impure function.

Haskell can call foreign functions whether they are pure or impure, you just need to give them appropriate signatures.  An impure function must be given an `IO a` return type.  A pure function can be given a non-`IO` return type.  (Of course, you *could* give a pure function an `IO` return type, too, but you don't have to and so usually wouldn't.)

For example, suppose we have the simple C++ "interface":

```
int value = 0;   // Haskell code sets value directly
extern "C" int getValue() { return value; }  // and gets it with this
```

If we **incorrectly** try to import `getValue` as a pure function:

```
foreign import ccall "interface.cc &value" valuePtr :: Ptr CInt
foreign import ccall "interface.cc getValue" getValue :: CInt  -- **NO NO NO!!!**
```

and test it like so:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  print getValue
  poke valuePtr 5
  print getValue
```

we get incorrect output:

```
0
0
```

Instead, we need to give `getValue` a type `IO CInt`:

```
foreign import ccall "interface.cc getValue" getValue :: IO CInt
```

With appropriate modifications to the rest of the program:

```
import Foreign
import Foreign.C

foreign import ccall "interface.cc &value" valuePtr :: Ptr CInt
foreign import ccall "interface.cc getValue" getValue :: IO CInt

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print =<< getValue
  poke valuePtr 5
  print =<< getValue
```

the output is as expected:

```
0
5
```

Note that it's only the **return** value that should be given an `IO` type.  If we add an impure function that takes arguments, like:

```
extern "C" int getMultValue(int scale) { return value*scale; }
```

then you'd use:

```
foreign import ccall "interface.cc getMultValue" getMultValue :: CInt -> IO CInt
```

The full programs:

```
// interface.cc
int value = 0;
extern "C" int getValue() { return value; }
extern "C" int getMultValue(int scale) { return value*scale; }

-- Main.hs
import Foreign
import Foreign.C

foreign import ccall "interface.cc &value" valuePtr :: Ptr CInt
foreign import ccall "interface.cc getValue" getValue :: IO CInt
foreign import ccall "interface.cc getMultValue" getMultValue :: CInt -> IO CInt

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print =<< getValue
  poke valuePtr 5
  print =<< getValue
  print =<< getMultValue 5
```

Note that things will get a little more complicated when the functions or variables in question are actually methods / instance variables.  Haskell doesn't directly support working with C++ objects, so you need to build some kind of `extern "C"` interface and pass object pointers as explicit arguments.  If you run into trouble a little further along in your design, maybe post additional questions and we'll try to help.